# Setting the style on a xaml button programmatically fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, silverlight

I'm working on a control. This control needs to be styled with input from an external source. I've looked for solutions and found a few that didn't break the code. However it is not styling the button. I set the style to the resources. Apply a reference to it on the button. Initialize the content, but the styles are not applied.

```
     public MainPage()
    {

        //String[] settings = Application.Current.Resources["settings"].ToString().Split(new Char[1] { '\u003A' });

        String[] settings = "_icons/pngp/2933.png:1:ff0000:Select files from disk...:36:36".Split(new Char[1] { '\u003A' });

        //style the dialog button
        ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush();
        image.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(settings[0], UriKind.Relative));
        Button dialogButton = new Button();

        dialogButton.Background = image;

        var styleOverride = new Style(typeof(Button)) ;
        styleOverride.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(0)));
        styleOverride.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BorderBrushProperty, colorConverter(settings[2])));
        styleOverride.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(double.Parse(settings[1]))));
        this.Resources.Add("key", styleOverride);

        dialogButton.Style = this.Resources["key"] as Style;
        dialogButton.Height = double.Parse(settings[4]);
        dialogButton.Width = double.Parse(settings[5]);
        //attach the click handler;
        dialogButton.Click += dialogButton_Click;

        ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
        tooltip.Content = settings[3];

        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(dialogButton, tooltip);


        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(dialogButton);
        this.LayoutRoot.Drop += this.Canvas_Drop;
    }
```

I've hardcoded the `settings` string. Normally this is dynamic and comes from an external resource. The question is why is `dialogButton.Style = this.Resources["key"] as Style;` not applying the desired style effects?

The image shows the result now (left) and the desired effect (right). No rounded border and a different border-color. And no, red isn't going to be the final color. It's for debugging.

[image]

Comment: Been a wile since I ASPd, but doesn't it have to draw/redraw the entire page like a bagillion times for every rounded corner? Wouldn't it be easier to just use a background image?

Comment: Really don't know. It's old and it's just for backup when HTML5 isn't around. But I cannot get it to set the style via code. If I use a template in the xaml all is fine, but via code, no dice.

Comment: Can you do something like this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182758/Dynamic-Theming-in-Silverlight)? What I know from WPF is that there are some cases where setting properties from C# has no effect and I had create XAML in C# and parse it manually. (For the case it would be helpful to you: I once used a similar approach to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

First, you are using `Border.BorderBrushProperty` and `Border.BorderThicknessProperty` which are not the dependency properties in `Button` control. You should change them to `Button.BorderBrushProperty` and `Button.BorderThicknessProperty` respectively, like the following -

```
styleOverride.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BorderBrushProperty, colorConverter(settings[2])));
styleOverride.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(double.Parse(settings[1]))));
```

The second issue is that there's no `CornerRadius` dependency property in a `Button` control. So you can't simply change it to `Button.CornerRadiusProperty`.

The workaround is, define a local `Button` `Style` inside your page, and then use `TemplateBinding` to bind the `CornerRadius` of the `Border` (inside the `ControlTemplate` of the `Button`) to the `Tag` dependency property. This part is easier to be done in xaml.

```
CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
```

And then, you just need to apply the `Style` as the `BaseOn` of your override `Style` and update the `Tag` property instead.

```
var styleOverride = new Style(typeof(Button))
{
    BasedOn = (Style)this.Resources["ButtonStyle1"]
};

styleOverride.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.TagProperty, new CornerRadius(0)));
```

Here attaches the full xaml `Button` `Style`.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#D8FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#C6FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#8CFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#3FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="White" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Tag}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1" d:IsHidden="True">
                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" Opacity="0" d:IsHidden="True"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" d:IsHidden="True">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" d:IsHidden="True"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tested the code and the result is exactly what you expected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just a side note, if not for other reasons you can assign an existing style to the button n then do button.Tag = ...; button.BordetBrush = ...; etc.

Comment: Thanks a million. Not only does your code works, it explained a lot! I've been helped! Collect your prize money.

Comment: Yes, I was really stuck. I followed the guidelines and I couldn't get it to style. I think am just to stuck to the DOM way of styling and XAML is really something completely different.

Comment: Yes it's quite different. However it can be very powerful too once you get your hands on it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do not set Style in code behind directly:

```
dialogButton.Style = this.Resources["key"] as Style;
```

but with `SetValue` method:

```
var style = this.Resources["key"] as Style; // or this.TryFindResource("key") as Style;
dialogButton.SetValue(StyleProperty, style);
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't cutting it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like style is applyed, but red border overlays png.
Try to comment out line:

```
/* styleOverride.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BorderBrushProperty, colorConverter(settings[2]))); */
```

Now background image become visible.
Maybe solution is to resize image to 40x40 pixels with margins?

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't the case here. I need the border to get a specific color and the border radius should be 0.